# get java.lang.ClassCastException when using EncryptedSharedPreferences

Tags: android

```
implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"


val sharedPrefsFile = "secret_shared_prefs"
val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
    sharedPrefsFile,
    MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
    context,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
)
```

when EncryptedSharedPreferences.create() runs, the following exception throws:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreECPrivateKey cannot be cast to javax.crypto.SecretKey